# PHP Storm markdown: text formatting problem after using code

Tags: formatting, markdown, expandable

I'm new to PHPStorm and coding. I think I have an easily solvable problem.
So I have to create an overall explain from a site, i was told to sneak in some images, i've managed to create expandable things with images. 
The main problem here is when i try to paste my code which creates an expandable with the image i want the rest of the text under the code just losts its "list behaviour", i dont know how to say better, i can add an empty line after the code which results in the text will be in a markdown box becouse its like this:

```
- Alapadatok: Az éttermek megadhatják a pontos adataikat
***i want my expandable with my image here***
    - Alapadatok
        - étterem neve
        - étterem AL url-je
        - irányítószám, város, utca, házszám
        - helyazonosító, hosszúság, szélesség
    - Galéria: Képfeltöltés lehetősége az étterem kinézetéről, ételeiről stb
```

I have this code for the expandable:

```
<details>

  <summary> Image </summary>

![](admin/admin2.bmp)

</details>
```

[Image from the text after using empty line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m3Yz.png) 
[Without the empty line my text what ppl will see looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vvkO.png) 
[instead this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQzp6.png)
[Box thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBPCF.png)

So how can i get rid of that box since i must leave a blank line before and after my code without breaking the "list" appearance?

I hope i gave u enough information and u can help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't totally clear, but I think you're doing something like this:

```markdown
- List item 1

<details>

  <summary> Image </summary>

![](admin/admin2.bmp)

</details>

    - List item 1.1
        - List item 1.1.1
        - List item 1.1.2
    - List item 1.2
```

In this example, the `<details>` tag is outside the list and therefore ends it. The indented block started with `- List item 1.1` is being rendered as a [code block](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode).

Assuming the `<details>` tag is supposed to be part of `- List item 1`, it must be indented:

```markdown
- List item 1

    <!-- Indent this by four spaces to make it part of List item 1 -->
    <details>

        <summary> Image </summary>

        ![](admin/admin2.bmp)

    </details>

    - List item 1.1
        - List item 1.1.1
        - List item 1.1.2
    - List item 1.2
```

Now it won't end the list, which means you are free to continue it with `List item 1.1`.